# javascript fs.replace callback err catch

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've just started js programming, so just try to figure the grammar out.

And I think I understand the callback function's usage, but sometimes it makes me confusing still.

For example, look at this code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var fs = require('fs'),
oldPath = './input.js';

var tmp = oldPath.replace('wrong', 'output', function (err) {
    if(err) 
        console.log('rename callback ', err);
});
```

In this code, I expected 'if(err)' stats will catch the error status, because the oldPath doesn't include 'wrong' string.
But it didn't happen.

Finally, what I want to do is 'multiple file name change in a directory'.
So I made some js script and it works well on the shell but,
I want to catch the error situation, 
e.g. Can't find matched file name.

Please refer this url and thank you in advance.
https://github.com/nicejwjin/jsScript_FileRename/blob/master/change_filename

PS. On the reference of javascript documents, I can't understand why the API doesn't have any idea about this expression. 
Like this.
http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback

It just shows functions name and argument name and then callback and that's all.
I think I have to know how to figure it out on the document, the usage of the callback or other argument..

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The replace method on strings is synchronous - it doesn't have an asynchronous callback like most of the node.js functions. It replaces the first instance of the first argument with the second, and if it doesn't find the first argument anywhere, then it returns itself with no modifications:

```
"a b a b".replace("a", "cc") // returns "cc b a b"
"a b a b".replace("x", "yy") // returns "a b a b"
```

To detect if the first argument actually appears in the string, you can use indexOf:

```
if (str.indexOf("hello") === -1) {
  // str does not contain "hello"
} else {
  // str contains "hello"
}
```